what can i use to implement a BACnet server on ubuntu?
I have an embebed arm computer that for the sake of discussion is essentially a raspberry pi. I need to implement a bacnet server to communicate with a Building Management System (BMS), and I need the ability to implement MS/TP (modbus over bacnet). This computer has integrated modbus. I have looked at a variety of packages. bacpypes3 seemed promising, but it wont handle MS/TP. I've looked around the repos, and havent found much. There seems to be a lot of depreciated projects from 20 years ago, but not much for current support.
BACnet and BMS are very much still around, and from what I can tell poking around gateways is that they're all using linux, but made their software proprietary.
I'm looking for a software that can handle this operation, or an API, and... maybe a tutorial on setting up a bacnet server on Ubuntu.
While I am not a huge fan of proprietary software, I am willing to pay, if it means my project can get up an running in the near future.
